# Securing application against XSS

Tags: security, xss, owasp

We are currently using OWASP Antisamy project to protect our application against XSS attacks. Every input field is sanitized when any given form is submitted to server. It works fine, but we have issues with the fields like company name, organization name, etc.

Ex: Ampersand is escaped for AT&T and the company name is displayed wrong (displayed with escaped characters).

We manually update the fields on database to fix this issue. However, this is a pain in the neck as you can imagine.

Is there a way to address this using OWASP antisamy or should we use a different library?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should only encode on *output*, not on input. If a user enters `AT&T` in your application, this should be stored at `AT&T` in the database. There is no need to encode it, but of course make sure that you are using parameterised queries which will prevent characters such as `'` from breaking out of the SQL command context and causing SQL injection.

When you output, this is the only time you need to encode characters. e.g. `AT&T` should be encoded as `AT&amp;T` when output to HTML, so it is displayed in the browser as `AT&T`.

It seems like your application is encoding the input and also encoding the output, so strings like above will be double encoded at then output as `AT&amp;amp;T` in your HTML, causing the problem. Remove your input encoding to solve this.

The reason you should only encode when output is that if you decide you want to output data to a different format such as JSON or JavaScript, then the encoding is different. `O'leary` would become `O\x27leary` if encoded properly for JavaScript, which would not display properly in HTML where the encoding is `O&#039;leary`.