# What is the difference between CORS and CSPs?

Tags: security, cors, content-security-policy, cross-site

From my perspective, the technologies referred to as **Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)** and **Content Security Policies (CSPs)** seem to be very similar in purpose and implementation.

Both seem to allow you to whitelist the origins of resources which an uncompromised version of your webpage incorporates, via HTTP response headers. The only difference I can see is that CSPs seem to be more fine-grained in what you can approve in your HTTP response.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

CORS allows the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) to be relaxed for a domain.

e.g. normally if the user logs into both `example.com` and `example.org`, the Same Origin Policy prevents `example.com` from making an AJAX request to `example.org/current_user/full_user_details` and gaining access to the response.

This is the default policy of the web and prevents the user's data from being leaked when logged into multiple sites at the same time.

Now with CORS, `example.org` could set a policy to say it will allow the origin `https://example.com` to read responses made by AJAX. This would be done if both `example.com` and `example.org` are ran by the same company and data sharing between the origins is to be allowed in the user's browser. It only affects the client-side of things, not the server-side.

CSPs on the other hand set a policy of what content can run on the current site. For example, if JavaScript can be executed inline, or which domains `.js` files can be loaded from. This can be beneficial to act as another line of defence against [XSS](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss) attacks, where the attacker will try and inject script into the HTML page. Normally [output would be encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22983608/413180), however say the developer had forgotten only on one output field. Because the policy is preventing in-line script from executing, the attack is thwarted.

Comment: Much clearer and to the point than all mozilla/html5rocks/w3c documents together. Thx.

Comment: That's not quite true - The Same Origin Policy will not prevent the AJAX request by default.  It will only prevent the browser from accessing the result of the operation.  Also, CORS can do more than just relax SOP.  It can also further restrict - e.g. when "\*" is used as the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header, the browser will *not* send cookies and it will pre-flight certain requests.

Comment: @Veita That's what I meant by `and gaining access to the response`, the **and** is key here. I also clarify this further on: `it will allow the origin https://example.com to read responses made by AJAX`

Comment: @veita Adding the header doesn't cause any extra preflights, this is in the hands of the code on the calling domain. Whether cookies are sent are also under control of the calling site (and the browser ofc), eg. `withCredentials`. Non-CORS requests (ie. Those that could be sent via HTML only), send cookies as normal. Think about it, by the time the browser has read the headers it's too late, cookies have already been sent.

Comment: Ah good point about the *and* in your initial response.  As for my comment regarding pre-flight - I meant the CORS standard itself introduces that, not a particular header.  For example, now that we have the CORS standard, certain requests will pre-flight before initiating the request.  If the server responds with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: \*", the client will not send the request (nor the cookies) when it otherwise would have in a pre-cors era.  My point being, the CORS standard seems to do more than relax SOP, as it prevents a request that would have initiated otherwise.

Comment: @Veita I understand what you're saying, but under the "pre-cors era" those requests wouldn't have been possible in the first place. That's why there is the pre-flight... These requests are now possible with extra headers, content types, etc, so the browser and the server need to make sure they both opt into CORS before they continue to communicate using the CORS specification. Therefore, CORS only relaxes cross domain communication Vs the "pre-cors era".

Comment: @SilverlightFox I could be wrong, but pre-cors, wouldn't the requests have been sent, but the response unreadable?  Now, it seems the request isn't even sent to begin with.

Comment: @Veita No, the requests would not have been sent. Old browsers didn't support XHR cross-domain until CORS, except for IE8 in a very limited capacity which was even more restrictive than CORS.

Answer (score 122):

CORS allows a site A to give permission to site B to read (potentially private) data from site A (using the visitor's browser and credentials).

CSP allows a site to prevent **itself** from loading (potentially malicious) content from unexpected sources (e.g. as a defence against XSS).

Comment: can CSP be used on site A to prevent site A from reading data from site B? I am talking mainly about xhr requests.

Comment: Can I say that CORS is a subset of what can be done with CSP ?

Comment: @mathk — No. As I said in the answer, they are completely different things.

Comment: I mean if you do not allow the browser to download content from site B you will also guaranty that nothing will be sent to site B using CSP ?

Comment: @mathk — Site A preventing data being sent to Site B (which can be achieved with CSP) is completely different to Site B preventing Site A from reading data from it (which is the default behaviour but which can be relaxed with CORS).

Comment: Are we agree that: `Site A preventing data being sent to Site B` -> Browser can not do a `GET[other verb] A`.  and ` Site B preventing Site A from reading data from it ` Browser can not do a `POST B  <some data>` ?

Comment: @mathk — No. Nothing is stopping JS on site A triggering a post request to site B. The Same Origin Policy just stops site A's JavaScript from reading the response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186769/discussion-between-mathk-and-quentin).

Comment: When folks say these things are "completely different" that just makes the differences harder to understand because they aren't completely different. Same-origin policy (to which CORS is closely related) prevents reading cross-origin requests, the most common way a developer would come into contact with this policy. Likewise, one of the most common ways a developer would come into contact with CSP is because it is blocking cross-origin requests, e.g., in a greasemonkey script.

Comment: If this simple and clear answer is correct,  I wonder why MDN's documentation on this is so verbose and confusing.

Comment: @Asker — Because this is a one sentence summary of the purpose of each technology while MDN’s documentation is in-depth.

Comment: @Quentin MDN's documentation as of this writing is missing such a summary, which is a shame--MDN leaves much to be desired in writing quality. Their articles are also not as deep as the WHATWG documentation.

Comment: @Asker — You could edit the MDN documentation if you think it can be improved.

Answer (score 55):

@JodySowald's comment, which I find more succinct:

> Content-Security-Policy prevents calls to external resources and Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing prevents calls from external sources. To provide an example. For `example.com` to show `example.net` in an iframe, `example.com` must not block `example.net` with its CSP settings and `example.net` must not block `example.com` with its CORS settings.

---

Original answer:

None of the answers above give a clear and concise difference between CSP and CORS. Here is my way of thinking about them:

Let's say we have `example.com` website that wants to send a request to `example.net`.

1. When user visits `example.com` in browser, `example.com` server returns **`example.com` HTTP response**, CSP restriction within this response can prevent **`example.com` in browser** from issuing request to `example.net`.
2. If there is no CSP restriction within **`example.com` HTTP response**, then **`example.com` in browser** can send a request to `example.net`.
3. Upon receiving the request, `example.net` server responds with **`example.net` HTTP response**, CORS restriction within this response can prevent **`example.com` in browser** from loading it. (Note that by default, Same-origin policy will restrict the response from loading, unless otherwise specified by CORS)

So CSP protects `example.com` and same-origin policy (the lack of CORS) protects `example.net` in the example above.

Comment: In this example, wouldn't the Same Origin policy protect **def.net**, whereas CORS removes this protection if enabled?

Comment: @Steve you are right, it's kind of a misnomer, I've updated my answer to reflect it.

Comment: Is it a correct simplification to say that Content-Security-Policy prevents calls to external resources and Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing prevents calls from external sources?

to provide an example.
For abc.com to show def.net in an iframe, abc.com must not block def.net with its CSP settings and def.net must not block abc.com with its CORS settings.

Comment: @JodySowald that would seem fitting.

Answer (score 4):

**CORS** checks with the third party for authorization to use its services. So, the third party provides or denies authorization.

So for example if a page in `www.example.com` needs to make a request to `www.example.org`, [the browser sends](https://auth0.com/blog/cors-tutorial-a-guide-to-cross-origin-resource-sharing/) an `OPTIONS` request with `Origin: www.example.com` as a precursor to request for authorization. Now, `www.example.org` provides or denies authorization.

**CSP** prevents a webpage from inadvertently loading malicious content from a third party by specifying where a particular type of content can be loaded from. So, for example you can provide a valid source for each of the following scripts, css, media etc. by using directives

Example:

```http
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' www.google-analytics.com ajax.googleapis.com; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';
```

Answer (score 1):

#### [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

A response header that tells the browser to only allow specific sources access to your content, e.g.:

```http
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://onlinebanking.example.com
```

CORS was [invented in 2004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#History) and won't stop your content from talking to strangers and using replies for `*`, so [since 2013](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/05/content-security-policy-1-0-lands-in-firefox-aurora/) we have:

#### [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)

A response header that tells the browser to only allow specific sources to be accessed from the content:

```http
Content-Security-Policy: default-src https://onlinebanking.example.com
```

That can also be set or tightened via HTML:

```html
<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="default-src https://onlinebanking.example.com" />
```